# Set volume of Java Clip

Tags: java, audio, volume, clip

Is there any way to set the respective volume of a `Clip` in `Java`?

I have this method:

```
public static void play(Clip clip) {
    if (Settings.getSettings().isVolumeOn()) {
        FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        volume.setValue(-1 * Settings.getSettings().getVolume());
        clip.start();
    }
}
```

The `Settings.getSettings().getVolume()` returns an `Integer` in the range of `0 - 100`

> Volumes:
>
> 1. 0  : No Sound
> 2. 40 : Optimal Sound with headphones
> 3. 60 : Optimal Sound
> 4. 100: Full Sound

So essentially this should be like the scale of `VLC` (but half since VLC is from `0 to 200`).

I've found that I can reduce the decibel of the clip by using `volume.setValue(-10f);`

But I would prefer something of the type `volume.setValue(clip.getMaxVolume() * Settings.getSettings().getVolume()/100)`.

Where `clip.getMaxVolume()` would return the max volume of the clip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [Killer Game Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596007300.do) by Andrew Davison you can adjust volume this simple:

```
float range = gainControl.getMaximum() - gainControl.getMinimum();
float gain = (range * volume) + gainControl.getMinimum();
gainControl.setValue(gain);
```

`volume` being the desired volume in float (0.0f means no sound, 1.0f means full audio)
`gainControl` is the `FloatControl`

Hope you can get it to work!

Comment: Is `gainControl.getMinimum()` necessary? Wouldn't my method work? (Both versions work).

Comment: I've only tried this with one file, which is why I'm asking, do you believe that other files might not work with my method?

Comment: Ok, I'm accepting your answer, if you find out that your answer should be updated please do so.

Answer (score 16):

The [MASTER_GAIN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/FloatControl.Type.html#MASTER_GAIN) `FloatControl` value is in decibels, meaning it's a logarithmic scale, not a linear one.

While decibels is great for audio professionals, us programmers usually want a nice linear scale where `0.0` is silent, `0.5` is half volume, and `1.0` is full volume; by which I mean normal volume for the sound sample. When playing sound effects, we don't usually amplify sound clips, just attenuate them.

[Decibel (dB) to Float Value Calculator](http://www.playdotsound.com/portfolio-item/decibel-db-to-float-value-calculator-making-sense-of-linear-values-in-audio-tools/) explains the maths behind converting decibels to a linear scale, but here is the code:

In [Fantom](https://fantom-lang.org/):

```
using [java] javax.sound.sampled::Clip
using [java] javax.sound.sampled::FloatControl
using [java] javax.sound.sampled::FloatControl$Type as FType

...
private Clip clip

Float volume {
    get {
        gainControl := (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FType.MASTER_GAIN)
        return 10f.pow(gainControl.getValue / 20f)
    }
    set {
        if (it < 0f || it > 1f) throw ArgErr("Invalid volume: $it")
        gainControl := (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FType.MASTER_GAIN)
        gainControl.setValue(20f * it.log10)
    }
}
```

And converted to Java:

```
import javax.sound.sampled.Clip;
import javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl;

...

private Clip clip

public float getVolume() {
    FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);        
    return (float) Math.pow(10f, gainControl.getValue() / 20f);
}

public void setVolume(float volume) {
    if (volume < 0f || volume > 1f)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Volume not valid: " + volume);
    FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);        
    gainControl.setValue(20f * (float) Math.log10(volume));
}
```

Note there is no need to involve `clip.getMaxVolume()` or `clip.getMinVolume()` because using the code above, a volume of `1.0` corresponds to `0 Db` (no change) and a volume of `0.1` corresponds to `-20 Db` (very, very quiet).

If you did want to amplify the sound clip, then there's nothing stopping you from passing in `2.0` to double the normal volume, a-la VLC.

And as a shameless plug, to see what I've used this knowledge for - see [Escape the Mainframe](http://escape.fantomfactory.org/) - a mini jump game that runs in the Browser and as a desktop Java application. Written in [Fantom](https://fantom-lang.org/) - have fun!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're actually looking for the FloatControl.Type.VOLUME control, rather than MASTER_GAIN. Try this:

```
public static void setVolume(Clip clip, int level) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(clip);
    FloatControl volume = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.VOLUME);
    if (volume != null) {
        volume.setValue(level / 100.0);     
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it true that some Clips will throw an exception if you try to get the VOLUME control (e.g., java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported control type: Volume)?

Answer (score 1):

So after a bit of trial and error, I came up with this:

```
public static void play(Clip clip) {
    if (Settings.getSettings().isVolumeOn()) {
        FloatControl control = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        int volume = Settings.getSettings().getVolume();
        float range = control.getMinimum();
        float result = range * (1 - volume / 100.0f);
        control.setValue(result);
        clip.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you want to review Steve's answer; as he suggests decibels is not linear therefore your conversion will probably not be what a user would expect, like setting volume to 0.5 will not be half the volume of the clip.