# Volume of BufferedInputStream?

Tags: java, audio, inputstream, volume

I have seen that you could adjust the volume of **Clip**, but after googling "Set volume of FileInputStream/BufferedInputStream", there wasn't really answers.

Is it possible to set this FIS/BIS audio volume? I use those in my MP3 player and want to make a method, where you could adjust the volume.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You realize that `FileInputStream` and `BufferedInputStream` deal with general streams and thus don't have any notion related to audio data, don't you? If you want to set a volume you'd probably have to do that in whatever object (e.g. a player, converter, etc.) you feed that stream into.

Comment: @Thomas Which part of the question makes you think that he realized that? ;-)

Comment: Nope, I did not know that. That's why this forum is here to let you ask questions :)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514910/set-volume-of-java-clip

Comment: I saw that topic, but is there a way to "set" the InputStream as clip or should I just use AudioInputStream instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since setting the volume of a `BufferedInputStream` makes as much sense as adjusting the volume of your couch, it's more likely that you're looking for something like [Mixer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/sound/sampled/Mixer.html), which can be used to implement volume control.

It's been quite a few years since I've touched it, but it would allow you to adjust the volume with [something like](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/sound/)

```
Mixer mixer = // get Mixer somehow through a provider
FloatControl fc = (FloatControl)mixer.getControl(javax.sound.sampled.FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
fc.setValue(1.0f);
```

Comment: My couch is pretty loud as I sit on it :o But yeah, I will check out and try to somehow get this to fit in my script. By the way, I used this tutorial from YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LavMuqK5Is0&list=UULuXaf-zBsw8Lzz6nqr66Jw] to make the mp3. Just wanted to make a MP3 player with tutorial, and do the rest within myself (like add audio volume and able to rewind the song etc...).