# Set volume of a Java Clip method not working

Tags: java, audio

Im trying to set the volume of a Clip in Java and Im fairly new to audio programming

Im following a previous post [Set volume of Java Clip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40514910/set-volume-of-java-clip) andswer by Steve but am having trouble using the method.

This is my working code just testing to play an audio file

```
try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Windows\\Media\\alarm01.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        //clip.setVolume(1.0f);
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

where the commented out line is the one that is producing the error. Below is my entire code in this class

```
public class Sound {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    
    private static Clip clip;

    public float getVolume() {
        FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        return (float) Math.pow(10f, gainControl.getValue() / 20f);
    }

    public static void setVolume(float volume) {
        if (volume < 0f || volume > 1f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Volume not valid: " + volume);
        }
        FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);
        gainControl.setValue(20f * (float) Math.log10(volume));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int vol;
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().beep();
        try {
            vol = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            vol = 0;
        }
        try {
        AudioInputStream audioInputStream = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("C:\\Windows\\Media\\alarm01.wav").getAbsoluteFile());
        Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
        //clip.setVolume(1.0f);
        clip.open(audioInputStream);
        clip.start();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error with playing sound.");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The reason for the int vol in main is because that is whats meant to actual be the parameter to set the volume once I can get that method working

When I try to do the line

```
clip.setVolume(int);
```

it says it cannot find the symbol for the method setVolume and im not sure why

Comment: maybe https://stackoverflow.com/users/1532548/steve-eynon knows

Answer (score 0):

The `clip.setVolume()` in your code is looking for a `setVolume` method on the class `Clip`.

The `getVolume()` that you created applies to the class `Sound`.

Comment: So do you know how I would fix that then? I thought my setvolume class did apply to clip

Comment: You have two distinct `Clip` instances: one that you create in the main() method and another that is declared as a static instance variable in the `Sound` class and is referenced in the Sound class methods. Use one or the other throughout!

Comment: You might need to get a better grip on the basics of `static` and instance variables first. Might be good to review those concepts if they are new to you. They are basic/fundamental to Java. I can't tell from your post if you have them down or not.

Comment: To be clear, if I remove the "clip." and just leave the line as setVolume when I call it, I get a nullpointer exception in that line and in the line that reads  FloatControl gainControl = (FloatControl) clip.getControl(FloatControl.Type.MASTER_GAIN);

Comment: Phil, just wanted to let you know that your comment helped me figure it out, I just had to create my own sound class that wasnt public. Sometimes I struggle with declaring methods and whether they should be public/static

Comment: Glad to hear it! This is a tricky aspect of Java and it can take a while to get the hang of it. But it is really important to master it. I think that this is a prime situation where going through the exercise of working out the relationships and logic is much more valuable than copy/pasting a coded solution in.